# Open "small" browser from Outlook

Tags: javascript, .net, browser, outlook, outlook-addin

I am going to make an Outlook add-in very soon.
It has the option, that if a user press a button, a browser should be opened, and the user should fill out the required forms on the URL.

Now I don't imagine it is any problem to open a browser from Outlook itself. But I suppose that if you just open a link, then the whole browser will be loaded up, with all tabs, full size and so on.

Is it possible to just open a small browser window, almost like a popup? No tabs or anything. It should just use the users default browser.

I hope you understand my question, and can guide me to a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question, take a look at the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class. You can put it in a simple windows forms application.

However, unless you have specific requirements to use a specialized browser, I would simply let the system default browser handle any links.

Answer (score 0):

Create and display a custom form. You can use a browser control in that window.